# How to add shaded area between curves having some NA?

Tags: r

From R Graph Gallery, very straightforward:

```
# Create data for the area to shade
cord.x <- c(-3,seq(-3,-1,0.01),-1) 
cord.y <- c(0,dnorm(seq(-3,-1,0.01)),0) 

# Make a curve
curve(dnorm(x,0,1), xlim=c(-3,3), main='Standard Normal') 

# Add the shaded area.
polygon(cord.x,cord.y,col='skyblue')
```

Now we add missing points

```
s <- sample(1:length(cord.x),4,T)
cord.x[s] <- NA
cord.y[s] <- NA

curve(dnorm(x,0,1), xlim=c(-3,3), main='Standard Normal') 
polygon(cord.x,cord.y,col='skyblue')
```

and the "wrong" area is shaded, i.e. the area that I would not like to be shaded...

The quickest solution would be to na.approx missing values, but is there a smart/automatic way to solve this? 
Add multiple polygons for each na.contiguous part of the curve?

Any suggestion is appreciated.
A

Comment: Is there any problem with using `cord.x[!is.na(cord.x)]`?

Comment: Or with `na.approx`? I don't believe there's an automatic way to do this and your suggestion in the question is actually smart.